# ¿Cómo destruir todas las instancias de los objetos encapsulados en un objeto principal de una sola vez en C#? (Destructor/delete[])

Tags: c#, objeto, delete, destructor

Resulta que tengo dos objetos que están relacionados entre si y ambos crean una copia de otro objeto y me gustaría que ambas se destruyeran secuencialmente de forma automática. (Pongo ejemplo para que se vea mas claro).

//-----------------------------------------------------

```
public class Disparo
{
    //el destructor no funciona hasta que se acaba la ejecucion del progrma
    ~Disparo()
    {
      this.Destroy();//esto destruye "FISICAMENTE" el objeto (no destruye la instancia).
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------
public class Enemigo
{
   public bool vivo;
   Disparo disparoOriginal;
   Disparo disparoCopia;

   public Enemigo()
   {
     disparoCopia = Clonar(disparoOriginal);
   }

    //el destructor no funciona hasta que se acaba la ejecucion del progrma
   ~Enemigo()
    {
       disparoCopia.Destroy();//esto destruye "FISICAMENTE" el objeto (no destruye la instancia).
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------
public class CreadorDeEnemigos
{    
    Enemigo enemigoOriginal;
    Enemigo enemigoCopia[10];
    int vidas=0;

    public void Loop()
    {
      if(!enemigoCopia[vidas].vivo && vidas<3)
      {
        enemigoCopia[vidas].disparoCopia.Destroy();//--> funciona pero no lo veo práctico
        enemigoCopia[vidas].Destroy();
        vidas++;
        enemigoCopia[vidas] = Clonar(enemigoOriginal);
      }
    }
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------

El problema es que en C# no encuentro nada que haga lo mismo que el **delete[]** de C++, es decir que haciendo

```
delete[] enemigoCopia[count];
```

llamaría automáticamente al destructor de ~Enemigo() que a su vez llamaría al destructor de ~Disparo() y destruiria todos los objetos de una sola vez.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder destruir un objeto y todas los objetos contenidos en él sin tener que esperar a que acabe la ejecución del programa?

Gracias!!

Comment: Tus objetos los estas referenciando a un array el array contiene tu elemento y no se eliminara hasta que el array deje de estar en memoria,  lo mejor es que tu enemigo[x]= null; asi no habra referencia alguna.

Comment: Gracias!! voy a probarlo!!

Comment: Aun cuando tu referencia sea a nulo, lo que haces con tu objeto es que sea elegible para Garbage collector, y la mayoria de las veces este garbage collector no elimina la memoria hasta que el programa ha finalizado, solo como nota.

Comment: Me conformo con que el segundo objeto también sea destruido... lo que me está pasando es que al destruir el enemigo la bala sigue viva e intenta localaizar la posición del enemigo que ya no existe y me está dando el tipico error de NULL refecence... Sería genial que al destruir al enemigo se destruyera la bala tambien ya que fue el enemigo quien la creó... pero es una la lata que el destructor no se ejecute porque si no lo haría ahí y sería mas comodo...